# Insert data in access file using dataset

Tags: c#

I want to insert data into a access file.
I dont want to insert it directly with insert into but using a dataset

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text != "")
    {
        string q = "insert into info (name) values ('"+textBox1.Text.ToString()+"')";
        aanpassen(q);
        textBox1.Text = null;               
    }
}
```

Here is the other part

```
 private void aanpassen(String q)
    {
        try
        {

            cn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = q;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
            loaddata();

            //connection
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());
        }
       finally
       {
       cn.Close();
       }
    }
```

Comment: You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for SQL Injection attacks. And what `aanpassen` method do? Why do you need dataset? You just inserting a data, not returning it.

Comment: What does `loaddata()` do?

Comment: Look into a `DataAdapter`. MSDN has a good walkthrough: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254931(v=vs.110).aspx